# javac 1.8.0_77 on Mac OS X v10.11.4 inconsistent compilation results on different systems

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting compiler errors when I compile the code below on my Mac. However, when I compile the same code on [compilejava.net](https://www.compilejava.net/) it runs fine. I believe compilejava.net is running javac 1.8.0_77 as of this writing.

I am using javac 1.8.0_77 on my Mac. My Mac is running OS X v 10.11.4
I tried javac 1.8.0_92 on my Mac with the same results.
Is anyone able to enlighten me on what may be wrong?

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CompilerError {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> tally = new HashMap<>();
    LinkedList<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> list = new LinkedList<>(tally.entrySet());
  }
}
```

Error (result of running > javac CompilerError.java):

```
CompilerError.java:6: error: cannot infer type arguments for LinkedList<>
    LinkedList<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> list = new LinkedList<>(tally.entrySet());
                                                  ^
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) E
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class LinkedList
1 error
```

Output of java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

Output of javac -version

```
javac 1.8.0_77
```

Comment: Post the output of `java -version`. Works fine for me with OpenJDK 1.8.0_92.

Comment: Your IDE is probably using a different version of Java than you think

Comment: @Kon Good thought, but I am just typing it up in Sublime and running javac on the file from the command line.

Comment: Could it be that there is some `LinkedList.java` or  `LinkedList.class` class file in the same directory? Try it with a fresh, empty directory that *only* contains your relevant file, and/or (in doubt) change the imports to explicitly `import java.util.LinkedList;`

Comment: @Marco13 that was it! That was very very astute of you to point that out. I was working in a folder that contained a lot of files I used to practice coding over the years. I forgot that I had implemented a simple linked list of my own named LinkedList.class. I have learned my lesson and will not name my classes the same as the ones in the Java library.

Comment: So I'd vote to close because the problem was caused by a "... simple error..." (as described in the close reason).

Comment: @Marco13 I agree that while the nature of the error is simple, someone may run into the same problem. When you say close it, does it mean delete the question?

Comment: Not necessarily - but there is a somewhat complex machinery running behind the scenes - see e.g. [this meta post about deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). I'm not sure whether someone would have *exactly the same* problem and find this question (and consider it helpful), because obviously, when there are wrong `.class` files, there can be "arbitrary" error messages. But until now, it's only one vote. Let's see how it turns out ... ;-)